# Using regex for HTML-parsed text

Tags: regex, xml, string

Based on the following text returned from the server storing an HTML-parsed text string for tagging users, how do I use regex here for the name, "Dave Park":

```
[u=8367|Dave Park]&nbsp;
```

I tried the following regex, but to no avail:

```
|(\\w*)]
```

Comment: You need to escape `|`; it's regex symbol for "OR". For that matter, in some regex implementations the closing bracket also needs to be escaped. On the other hand, I have no idea why you escaped the \ in `\w`; that makes it a literal string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you seem to have escaped exactly what you shouldn't escape, and have not escaped several special symbols in regex that *do* need escaping.

Taking the full pattern, and escaping the correct part and adding the capture group, you should end up with this:

```
\[u=\d+\|([^\]]+)\]
```

This matches a literal `[` bracket, the `u=` string followed by multiple numbers, and then the literal `|`, then the group containing any characters that are not a closing `]` bracket, and finally, the literal closing `]` bracket.

[Test it out yourself](https://regex101.com/r/oPICaE/1)

I'm sort of wondering why you're not also capturing the obvious ID in the first part, but, well, you can do that simply by putting round brackets around the `\d+` in my posted pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. You needed to escape the | character and include spaces as a legal character in your capture group. So something like this:

```
\|([\w ]*)]
```

Comment: Indeed. But it's naive to use `\w` for names, since any special character in the name will break it.